# BizTalk Oracle WCF adapter insert or update

Tags: oracle, wcf, biztalk

I'd like to fire a message with multiple rows at Oracle and let the adapter either insert or, if the key field value already exists, update. Does anyone know if it's possible to achieve this without writing an oracle stored procedure / package or similar. This message to be inserted will contain approx 50k rows and the table into which it inserts will contain approx 500k. I realise I could pull the existing data first then manually check within an orchestration if I need to update or insert but I have a feeling I've read previously that it's possible to have the WCF adapter take care of determining whether and update or insert is required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The oracle adapter can accept inserts or deletes. The solution to my problem was to issue a single request to the adapter from BizTalk which contained a delete + inserted for any row to be updated. There's a property of the adapter called "UseAmbientTransactions", by ensuring this is set to true I prevent the possibility of having records deleted without a subsequent update.

If you find this helpful, please feel free to up vote the question - currently set at -2!